# Como resetar estado de formulário com dados de model?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angularjs

Tenho um model no qual preenche os campos de um formulário (uso asp.net mvc e a view é tipada), ou seja, carrego os campos deste formulário de acordo com os dados do banco de dados para o usuário alterar na tela de edição.

O eu quero fazer é um botão de "desfazer" que reseta para o estado inicial dos dados que vieram do banco, não simplesmente usando o this.meuform.reset() no click do botão.

Acredito que deve ser feito no onLoad() do form uma forma de salvar os elementos atuais do form e quando clicado no botão, simplesmente jogar de novo nos elementos, estes elementos salvos...

Prefiro em Javascript puro.

Comment: Cara, não ficou muito claro pra mim o que você quer fazer. O `reset()` por si só já *reseta* os valor para o estado inicial, ou seja, voltar o valor dele para o que está no atributo `value`, que foi setado inicialmente. Agora, não entendi seu último parágrafo.

Comment: é que o reset ele "zera" todos os campos, coloca "" em todos os valores certo? Eu quero deixar os campos com os valores do model, por exemplo: busco no banco o nome joão e preencho o input value com este nome, ai eu altero este nome novamente.. depois disso, quero clicar e voltar para o valor que havia voltado do banco que era "João".

Comment: Eu acho que não cara, o `reset` não limpa os valores e sim os reseta mesmo para o valor inicial, dá uma olhada [nesse exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mty1xjbx/). Até onde eu sei, o `Html.EditorFor` ou semelhante que você possa estar usando, gera o valor no atribute `value`, o que é o padrão correto. Então o reset era pra funcionar.

Comment: Realmente faz sentido, irei testar novamente, posso ter cometido algum erro, aviso aqui em seguida, caso resolva, pode postar como resposta.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown acredito que esteja funcionando realmente, mas eu gostaria de pegar o formulário sem precisar setar um nome ou ID para ele, pois isso teria que ficar setando em todos os forms de todas páginas, á alguma forma generica de pegar?

seria isso? document.getElementsByTagName("form").reset();

Comment: Não, esse tipo de escrita funciona em jQuery porque ele roda um loop internamente. O `getElementsByTagName()` retorna uma coleção que não tem método `reset()`. Você teria que rodar o loop você mesmo, [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mty1xjbx/1/)

Comment: tem como postar como resposta as duas dúvidas? Pode ser em jquery.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown olhe o comentário acima, se puder, aguardo. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Opa amigo, tem sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) como explicado na documentação...

> The HTMLFormElement.reset() method restores a form element's default values

deveria sim *resetar* o valor dos elementos ao estado original, e não limpá-los, deixando em branco ou coisas assim, como nesse [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mty1xjbx/).

O que pode ser feito no seu caso - que tem vários forms - seleciona-los e em um loop *resetar* a todos:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
// ou
// var forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");

for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++)
{
    forms[i].reset();
}
```

Ou com jQuery:

```
var forms = $("form");

for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++)
{
    forms[i].reset();
}
```

Demos [1](http://jsfiddle.net/mty1xjbx/2/), [2](http://jsfiddle.net/mty1xjbx/3/) ou [com mais elementos](http://jsfiddle.net/mty1xjbx/4/).

**UPDATE:**

Para pegar apenas o primeiro(ou único) form da tela:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
// ou
// var forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");

if (forms.length > 0)
{
    forms[0].reset();
}
```

Dessa forma você evita possíveis *exceptions* caso a rotina tente resetar um form que não existe.

Comment: eu só tenho um por view, ou seja, não precisaria do 'for', mas este "form" precisa ser o id do formulário em sí né? Não tem uma forma de pegar sem precisar inserir id por id por exemplo?

Comment: O `form` é a tag, e não o id. Ele vai pegar todos os `<form>` do documento, mas se você só tem um, é só acessar direto `document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].reset()`.

Comment: @LuizNegrini Dá uma olhada no último update.